# Sequelize association not syncing with model definition

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, type) => {
  const article_comment = sequelize.define('article_comments', {
    // attributes
    id: {
      type: type.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    positive_rating:{
      type: type.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    negative_rating:{
      type: type.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    comment:{
      type: type.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    updatedAt:{
      type: type.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    createdAt:{
      type: type.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
  }, {});
     article_comment.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
     article_comment.hasMany(models.article_comments_user_ratings,{foreignKey:'comment_id'});
     article_comment.hasMany(models.article_replies,{foreignKey:'comment_id'});
  };
  return article_comment;
};
```

And my rating for comments

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, type) => {
  const article_comments_user_ratings = sequelize.define('article_comments_user_ratings', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: type.INTEGER
    },
    rating:{
      type: type.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false
    },
    createdAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: type.DATE
    },
    updatedAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: type.DATE
    }
  }, {});
  article_comments_user_ratings.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    article_comments_user_ratings.belongsTo(models.article_comments)

  };
  return article_comments_user_ratings;
};
```

However, when I use the findOrCreate method, it only does `INSERT INTO "article_comments_user_ratings" ("id","rating","createdAt","updatedAt").` Which obviously is failing because In the database I also have the additional columns of user_id and comment_id for the article_comments_user_ratings table.

This isn't making any sense because with the sync() function, prior to moving to migrations, it was working.

I don't know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by defining the associations after defining the model.

Example:

```
const User = UserModel(sequelize, Sequelize)
const Comment = CommentsModel(sequelize, Sequelize)

User.hasMany(UserCommentRating,{foreignKey:'user_id'})
Comment.hasMany(UserCommentRating,{foreignKey:'comment_id'})
```

It seems that the assocations inside the model is deprecated.